# Retriving data from quickbook through webconnector using DevKit

Tags: php, web-services, quickbooks, qbxml, devkit

I am using DevKit to retrieve data from Quick Book through WebConnector.
I have inserted data successfully in Quickbook but in retrieving something going wrong.
when I execute the "example_web_connector_import.php" this page then I didn't retrieve data.

kindly guide me to retrive data from QuickBook.
when I reload page then it shows.

> `QuickBooks PHP DevKit Server v2.0 at /DevKit/docs/example_app_web_connector/example_web_connector_import.php
>      (c) "Keith Palmer"  
>      Visit us at: http://www.ConsoliBYTE.com/

Use the QuickBooks Web Connector to access this SOAP server.

```
QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server::handle() parameters: 
- $return = 1
- $debug  = 1

Misc. information: 
- Logging: 4
- Timezone: America/New_York (Auto-set: )
- Current Date/Time: 2014-05-30 03:44:59
- Error Reporting: 32767

SOAP adapter: 
- QuickBooks_Adapter_Server_Builtin

Registered handler functions: 
Array
(
[0] => __construct
[1] => authenticate
[2] => sendRequestXML
[3] => receiveResponseXML
[4] => connectionError
[5] => getLastError
[6] => closeConnection
[7] => serverVersion
[8] => clientVersion
)
```

Detected input:

Timestamp: 
 - 2014-05-30 03:44:59 -- process 0.08689`

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Error Reporting: 32767 shows.

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem:

> when I execute the "example_web_connector_import.php" this page then I didn't retrieve data.

You need to read up on how the Web Connector works:

- http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QuickBooks_Web_Connector_Overview

*You* should *not* be executing that page. You should be *running the Web Connector*, and *the Web Connector executes that page* to exchange data with QuickBooks.

Did you run the Web Connector?

Comment: Yes I run the Web Connector But Web connector shows error "1: A query request did not find a matching object in Quick Books" My Request code is same as I download DevKit and just change configrution.

Comment: Is there any data which has recently changed in QuickBooks, and thus needs to be synced?  It is fully expected that you *should* get that message.  Try running this SQL query, and run it again: DELETE FROM quickbooks_config;